# Dimensions Mismatch during Clone Model step of Final Export of Estimator

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-estimator, tf.keras

I'm creating a Tensorflow Estimator from a Keras model. Currently, the estimator is created, the model is trained, and the model is evaluated without issues. However, on the last evaluation, the model is exported because I use the FinalExporter API, and I get a dimensions mismatch error:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Performing the final export in the end of training.
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/austinguo/.../lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1659, in _create_c_op
    c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 3 for 'model/block5_conv1/Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [14,14,512], [3,3,512,512].
```

It appears that the issue occurs when the Keras model has `clone_model` called on it before export (the traceback below shows this). However, the dimensions mismatch error seems to imply I have an issue with my input pipeline, which doesn't make sense to me since I don't understand how my model can even train and evaluate without issues if the format of the input functions is incorrect or if my input pipeline is broken somewhere else.

The full traceback is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/austinguo/tf-keras_siamese/template/trainer/task.py", line 277, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/austinguo/tf-keras_siamese/template/trainer/task.py", line 262, in main
    experiment.run(estimator, args)
  File "/home/austinguo/tf-keras_siamese/template/trainer/experiment.py", line 102, in run
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 471, in train_and_evaluate
    return executor.run()
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 611, in run
    return self.run_local()
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 712, in run_local
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 358, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1124, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1158, in _train_model_default
    saving_listeners)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1408, in _train_with_estimator_spec
    any_step_done = True
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 788, in __exit__
    self._close_internal(exception_type)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 821, in _close_internal
    h.end(self._coordinated_creator.tf_sess)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 588, in end
    self._save(session, last_step)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 607, in _save
    if l.after_save(session, step):
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 517, in after_save
    self._evaluate(global_step_value)  # updates self.eval_result
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 537, in _evaluate
    self._evaluator.evaluate_and_export())
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 925, in evaluate_and_export
    is_the_final_export)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 958, in _export_eval_result
    is_the_final_export=is_the_final_export))
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/exporter.py", line 419, in export
    is_the_final_export)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/exporter.py", line 126, in export
    strip_default_attrs=self._strip_default_attrs)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1645, in export_savedmodel
    experimental_mode=model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.PREDICT)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 723, in export_saved_model
    checkpoint_path=checkpoint_path)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 827, in experimental_export_all_saved_models
    save_variables, mode=model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.PREDICT)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 897, in _add_meta_graph_for_mode
    config=self.config)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1112, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/keras.py", line 278, in model_fn
    labels)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/keras.py", line 201, in _clone_and_build_model
    optimizer_iterations=global_step)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/models.py", line 466, in clone_and_build_model
    clone = clone_model(model, input_tensors=input_tensors)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/models.py", line 271, in clone_model
    return _clone_functional_model(model, input_tensors=input_tensors)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/models.py", line 161, in _clone_functional_model
    **kwargs))
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 554, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 815, in call
    mask=masks)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 1002, in _run_internal_graph
    output_tensors = layer.call(computed_tensor, **kwargs)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 194, in call
    outputs = self._convolution_op(inputs, self.kernel)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 966, in __call__
    return self.conv_op(inp, filter)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 591, in __call__
    return self.call(inp, filter)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 208, in __call__
    name=self.name)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 1026, in conv2d
    data_format=data_format, dilations=dilations, name=name)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 788, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3300, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1823, in __init__
    control_input_ops)
  File "/home/austinguo/census/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1662, in _create_c_op
    raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 3 for 'model/block5_conv1/Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [14,14,512], [3,3,512,512].
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue.

The cause of the dimensions mismatch was my use of Tensorflow's experimental make_batched_features_dataset() Dataset API. This creates datasets that are already batched based on the specified batch size. However, for this to work, the input Tensors to the model need to have an additional -1 dimension in the beginning specifying batch, i.e. (-1, ...) where ... are the other shape dimensions.

Without this, the Tensors that are being served by the ServingInputReceiver are not the correct shape, though training can work if you accidentally batch the dataset again after make_batched_features_dataset() already batches the dataset.